# Let $f(x)=x \sin(x)$. Then $|f|$ is?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x)=x \sin(x)$. Then $|f|$ is ?

1. Differentiable at $x=\pi$
2. Differentiable at $x=0$
3. Uniformily continious on $\mathbb{R}$
4. Differentiable at $x=-\pi$

I think only 3 is correct. but how to prove it?

${{}}$

Comment: It’s definitely not uniformly continuous over $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Notice that for all $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$, $|f(x)| = f(x)$.

Comment: is it 2 the correct option